# Add column at beginning of CSV that specifies the .jpg name that the data came from

Tags: python, numpy, csv

I have a CSV file, called 'newfile1.csv'. Each value is a tuple, where the 2 numbers reflect an (x,y) coordinate on an image. There are 68 tuples in an image (and therefore 68 different coordinates). Each new image is shown on a new row.

I want to have the filename that each of the coordinates come from at the start of every row. So I want a new column at the beginning of the file, where the filename corresponds to the data in the row it is at the start of.

My code for the CSV looks like this:

```
# this creates a CSV file that the coordinates will be stored in, with a header of the coordinates


with open("new_file1.csv","a") as my_csv: 
        writer = csv.writer(my_csv)
        writer.writerow(["0", "1", "2", "3"... "67"])

# this loops through all images in my folder and generate 68 landmarks, then store these as one row on the CSV

from pathlib import Path

for filename in Path('/Users/.../neutral_front/').glob('*.jpg'):

    img = io.imread(filename) 
    dets = detector(img)

    for k, d in enumerate(dets):
        shape = predictor(img, d)

    vec = np.empty([68, 2], dtype = int)
    for b in range(68):
        vec[b][0] = shape.part(b).x
        vec[b][1] = shape.part(b).y

    a = [vec] #'vec' represents all 68 tuples for 1 image


# this adds the 68 coordinates into 1 row of the CSV


with open("new_file1.csv","a") as my_csv:    
        csvWriter = csv.writer(my_csv,delimiter=',')
        csvWriter.writerows(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need a 2-D array in this case. You can extend your numpy array to 69 items, instead of 68, iterate through items 1 through 69 and append a tuple, then add the filename to the first item.

```
vec = np.empty([69], dtype = int)
for b in range(1,69):
    vec[b] = (shape.part(b).x, shape.part(b).y)
vec[0] = filename.name
```

Comment: when trying that, I get the error for the `vec[b] = (shape.part(b).x, shape.part(b).y) ` line of code. It says "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.".

Comment: Ah, sorry. I don't have much experience with numpys. You could use this code with a standard python list though. I don't know how important it is for you to stick with a numpy